# List files based on content type from Amazon s3

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

Is it possible to list files based on content type like this http://cl.ly/9M7J with the c# api?
I have managed to fetch S3Objects via ListObjectsRequest but they don't have any content-type property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. You can only filter the list of objects based on their prefix (by using the ListObjectsRequest.Marker property).
A suggestion that might work in your case is organizing the content in folders in your bucket(s) upon upload, if you have that option.